# Solve $33x≡9$ (mod 29)

Tags: congruences

I'm having trouble solving congruences. I can't seem to find a method (a series of steps) to follow in order to find the solutions of a linear congruence. In particular, I have $33x≡9$ (mod 29). My thoughts: gcd (33,29) $=1$, so there is one solution. I don't know what to do next (I tried using Euclid's algorithm...). Thanks

Comment: If you have $33x+29y=1$ for some $x,y$ by the Euclidean algorithm, then why not multiply by $9$? Then $33\cdot 9x\equiv 9\mod 29$.

Comment: What happened when you tried using Euclid's algorithm?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ {\rm\ mod}\ 29\!:\ x\equiv \dfrac{9}{33}\equiv \dfrac{-20}{4}\equiv -5\equiv 24$

Such reduction and ad-hoc sign twiddling works quite well for small numbers. For larger numbers one can use the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) to invert the denominator. Or one can use [Gauss's algorithm,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242) since here the modulus is prime.

**Beware** $\ $ The use of fractions in modular arithmetic is valid only when the denominator is invertible, i.e. coprime to the modulus. Otherwise the quotient need not be unique, for example mod $\rm\:10,\:$ $\rm\:4\,x\equiv 2\:$ has solutions $\rm\:x\equiv 3,8,\:$ so the "fraction" $\rm\:x \equiv 2/4\pmod{10}\,$ cannot designate a unique solution of $\,4x\equiv 2.\,$ Indeed, the solution is $\rm\:x\equiv 1/2\equiv 3\pmod 5,\,$ which requires canceling $\,2\,$ from the *modulus* too, since $\rm\:10\:|\:4x-2\iff5\:|\:2x-1.\:$

Generally the grade-school rules of fraction arithmetic apply *universally* (i.e. in all rings) where the denominators are invertible. This fundamental property will be clarified conceptually when one learns in university algebra about the *universal properties* of fractions rings and localizations.

Comment: I avoid the beware part by ensuring that the linear congruence belongs to **case 1** of my notes [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/815871/85660) :)

Answer (score 1):

The Euclidean algorithm is indeed the method *par excellence* for computing modular inverses. Or more to the point, the *extended* Euclidean algorithm, which finds a solution to the equation

$$ 33 u + 29 v = 1$$

for you. (or it would solve $4u + 29v = 1$ for you, if you've already figured out that $33 \equiv 4$ and simplified the problem) (I put $1$ on the right hand side, since you already know the $\gcd$ is $1$)

How does this help you? Well, what happens if you simplify this equality modulo $29$?

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align} 33x=29y+9 & =>4x=29(y-x)+9 \\ & => y-x=2k+1\\ & =>2x=29k+19\\ & => k=2n+1\\ & => x=29n+24.\end{align} $$

Comment: I don't think $\Leftrightarrow$ means what you think it means.

Comment: It does, actually. :-) But the bright and brilliant minds that invented *LaTeX* did not see it fit to make up a short code for the (actual) $=>$ sign.

Comment: I suppose you're objecting to `\Rightarrow`. There is always `\implies`, though. Or just `\to` if you're happy with writing implication with a single line.

Comment: The $\to$ doesn't "jump out", unfortunately. Anyway, I'll stick with the $=>$.

Answer (score -2):

We have $$33=4\mod29$$ and $$4^{-1}=22\mod29$$ because $4(22)=88=29*3+1$. Therefore the answer is $$9*22=198=24\mod29$$

Comment: I've downvoted because it hands out the answer to the homework problem in a way that is unlikely to convey insight to most people who don't already know how to solve such problems.

Comment: I've ignored your downvote because it hands out an explanation in a way that is unlikely to convey insight to any but the most bored people.